# Was Dr Strange experiencing all the timeloops with Dormamu?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

It is made very clear that Dormamu is experiencing the loop at the end of *Doctor Strange* as a sequence of events, much like the viewer.

Indeed, that's the point - from his perspective he's going to 'live' these moments forever, getting bored and unable to proceed beyond them.

**Is Dr Strange experiencing that too?**
Or is Dr Strange's experience getting reset every time (with the note that he KNOWS conceptually that he is at some arbitrary point in the cycle?)

If he is experiencing it, then how is he planning to not get bored or give up to escape eternal torment? It's made clear that at least some of the deaths hurt. So it seems like he's merely set it up as "I reckon I can be more stubborn than you can" which seems ... less certain.

Answer (score 4):

> Is Dr Strange experiencing that too?

It seems entirely obvious that Strange is experiencing every sequence and, yes, he's aware of it. In fact he says so.

> D: Then you will spend eternity dying.
>
> S: Yeah. But everyone on Earth will live.
>
> D: **But you will suffer.**
>
> S: Pain is an old friend.

---

> If he is experiencing it, then how is he planning to not get bored or give up to escape eternal torment? It's made clear that at least some of the deaths hurt. So it seems like he's merely set it up as "I reckon I can be more stubborn than you can" which seems ... less certain.

The **whole point** is that he's **willing** to keep doing it *forever* to stop Dormammu...so yes he will "out-stubborn" him. That's the sacrifice he's willing to make.

> D: You will never win.
>
> S: No... But I can lose. Again, and again, and again, and again, forever.    And that makes you my prisoner.

As final evidence, on the final "loop", Strange continues the conversation from the previous one...which he could not do if he wasn't aware of it by having experienced it.

Right after being destroyed after the above "prisoner" speech

> D: Stop! Make this stop!!!
>
> S: Set me free! - No. I've come to bargain.

Comment: I'm still up in the air about this. Why would Dr. Strange keep saying the same line over and over, "Dormomu, I've come to bargain"? That seems to indicate he's experiencing it for the first time each time. If he was aware that he kept coming back, it seems as though he should say something more like "I'm back again" or "Are you willing to bargain yet?"

Comment: IIRC, Dr Strange excluded himself from the timeloops, i.e. he didn't experience them all.

Comment: He must have experienced them or from his point of view Dormammu would just give up on the first go round. Dormammu is aware of the loops why do you think Strange is not.? They are both in there together. As for the repeated lines, that's for the audience's benefit to indicate that there **is** a loop.

Comment: @Paulie_D - as Strange's intent is to bore Dormammu, opening with the same line each loop makes sense. If he opens with a unique line, Strange may have to suffer through more painful deaths before Dormammu gives up.I don't think it was just for the audience.